# How do I remove Cyber Security THE Rogue Anti-Spyware

Tags: windows, anti-virus, uninstall, spyware

I am not sure how many of you have heard of Cyber Security (no link, a rogue anti-spyware doesn't deserve a link).  Basically, it's a virus and a rogue masquerading as anti-spyware. You can read about how it forces users to BUY the software on the internet.

My question is, how do I completely remove Cyber Security?  A Google search reveals a lot of links; all require the download of equally dubious programs from equally dubious websites. I don't trust those links, therefore I turn to the SU community, and hope that I can get a better answer.

Comment: Removed comments as they were off-topic

Comment: Question protected due to multiple spam answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addidtion i would recommend a good 'honnest' spyware tool to aid with the removal, such as Malware Bytes (http://www.malwarebytes.org/) the free version is fine - just doesnt scan automatically and/or Spybot Search and destroy (http://www.safer-networking.org/index2.html)

I work in It as a network security administrator and these are very eay to use and hady tools to have.

Comment: another +1 for Malwarebytes. We use it all the time to get rid of rogue antivirus and antispyware programs on our customer's PCs.

Answer (score 4):

there is [Revo uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/)

> Revo uninstaller helps you to
>   uninstall software and remove unwanted
>   programs installed on your computer
>   even if you have problems uninstalling
>   and cannot uninstall them from
>   "Windows Add or Remove Programs"
>   control panel applet ...

Free

---

**EDIT**

maybe it won't work this way,
your PC is infected by a malware, so you will need an anti-virus.

Comment: Very good tool for this kind of thing indeed

Comment: Revo uninstaller is a great tool for that kind of thing, I second Revolter's answer (+1)

Answer (score 4):

> A Google search reveals a lot of
>   links; all require the download of
>   equally dubious programs from equally
>   dubious websites. I don't trust those
>   links

you don't have to download/install anything, you can remove Cyber Security manually:

`1.` **Stop The Following Cyber Security Processes:**

```
csc.exe
Computer Scan.lnk
Help.lnk
```

`2.` **Find and Delete The Following Cyber Security Files:**

```
c:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\CS
c:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\CS\Computer Scan.lnk
c:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\CS\Cyber Security.lnk
c:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\CS\Help.lnk
c:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\CS\Registration.lnk
c:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\CS\Security Center.lnk
c:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\CS\Settings.lnk
c:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\CS\Update.lnk
%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\CS.lnk
%UserProfile%\Desktop\Cyber Security.lnk
c:\Program Files\Common Files\CSUninstall
c:\Program Files\Common Files\CSUninstall\Uninstall.lnk
c:\Program Files\CS
c:\Program Files\CS\tsc.exe
c:\WINDOWS\system32\iehelpmod.dll
```

`3.` **Remove The Following Cyber Security Registry Values:**

```
**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\uninstall\CS
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{35A5B43B-CB8A-49CA-A9F4-D3B308D2E3CC}
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\5FFB10D58FFCF482208906E6A889FD56
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Browser Helper Objects\{35A5B43B-CB8A-49CA-A9F4-D3B308D2E3CC}
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run “CS”**
```

*[Source](http://www.xp-vista.com/spyware-removal/remove-cyber-security-removal-instructions)*

Answer (score 1):

My daughter (age 15) had something very similar called 'Security Tool' on her PC.

It posed as anti-virus, anti-spyware, all the time popping up fake warnings and asking for credit-card details so you could buy virus removal software.

Needless to say, we did no such thing. The final solution was to ask one of her school friends how to remove it.

So there you go, you need a 15-year-old boy who understands computers.

Comment: well, ain't that the sad truth ... :)

Comment: @molly7244: Sad? Look at my profile?

Answer (score 0):

After you remove it I would also recommend Super Anti Spyware as a scanner. Last resort would be [Combofix](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/combofix/how-to-use-combofix)